# My plug in may be bad. I'd like to make it a regular plug instead of GFCI

Tags: gfci

Can I just cut the small group of twisted wires and use the three big wires to install a standard plug. Or do those wire go to something inside the unit that will make it not work?
[image]

Comment: What is that plug for ? Why do you have push buttons on the side ?

Answer (score 3):

Just because it has "test" and "reset" doesn't mean it's a GFCI.

I have seen reports of people attempting to circumvent the LDCI end in ignominious failure.  There's more going on than GFCI, the extra wires matter.

LDCI replacement cords are readily available.

These things get installed because people keep dying from them not being installed.  If your unit is as weathered as this plug in, you have to consider the possibility that **maybe the actual unit is faulty**.

People are weirdly in denial about electrical faults.  When a fault detector goes off, they  always want to believe there's nothing wrong with their equipment and it's a detector fault.  Meanwhile, if a radon detector goes off, they assume they have radon, even though they can't see radon either.

Comment: Edjumacate me (us): how do you distinguish a gfci from an ldci from the pic? (Or from an outside view?)

Comment: What is an LDCI?

Answer (score 0):

Would it work? Yes. But it would be against the manufacturer's original design as approved (hopefully...) by UL, ETL, etc.

There are many plug-in appliances which are supplied with a GFCI plug. Those are often the same appliances where the receptacle, according to current (pun intended) code requires GFCI. Classic example: hair dryer and bathroom. The GFCI concern about a hair dryer really only applies around water, as when used in a bathroom. However, since *many* bathroom receptacles don't have GFCI protection (there is no requirement, at least in most places, to add GFCI protection if you don't make any changes to the original circuit), the hair dryer manufacturers include GFCI in the plug. If you use it with a GFCI/receptacle (or GFCI/breaker protected circuit), you get double protection which does not cause a problem.

So replacing with a plain plug gets rid of that protection. If your bathroom circuits are not GFCI protected, that is a really bad idea. Even if they are protected, consider that some day you might move and take the hair dryer with you and find that the old bathroom circuits in your new (but not "new") home don't have GFCI protection.

Replacements are available at hardware stores, Home Depot, etc. *Make sure any replacement is UL or ETL listed*. The last thing you want is a safety device that isn't safe!

The one catch is that a GFCI plug may cost as much as an entire new appliance, particularly for small things such as hair dryers. But that is the nature of the parts replacement business vs. mass-market finished goods.

Some answers and comments indicate this might not be a GFCI plug. If it is some other protective device, you should install a compatible replacement. But the basic answer is the same: replace with the correct item, not a simple plug.

Comment: The thing pictured is not actually a GFCI.